Does Prisma have a way to disconnect or delete? (inverse of createOrConnect)
I have a many-to-many relationship between users and lists.  Users can connect and disconnect themselves from these lists. If the only user of a list gets disconnected, is there a way to automatically delete the list itself?  Mainly so I don't end up with orphaned lists floating around in the ether.
Perhaps this is possible through referential actions?
I'm using postgres under the hood fyi.
